# "Your startup disk is almost full" with tons of available space and mysql count distinct

Tags: mysql, macos, count, storage

I faced this "Your startup disk is almost full" with 16GB available space shown by storage in about this mac when I execute

```
SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT(col_name1)), col_name2
FROM table_name
GROUP BY col_name2;
```

a simple query working on a at most 5g data table.
Here is the EXPLAIN information:

> ## id, select_type, table, type, possible_keys, key, key_len, ref, rows, Extra
>
> '1', 'SIMPLE', 'patients_disease_drugs', 'ALL', NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, '12808761', 'Using filesort'

And btw, I have checked the col_name1 has been covered in INDEX of this table.

How big space is this query gonna take (more than 16G ???). and is there any advice to fix it?

Answer (score 0):

Once I changed all the variable type to INT relatd type that could resort to INDEX to boost query performance, it finally works, but seriously why this query cost so many spaces. Still wondering the answer ...

Answer (score 0):

I would hazard a guess that your query may have created a temporary table on disk in your tmp directory and took up all the available space.

Try adding an index on either (col_name1,col_name2) or (col_name2,col_name1) and see if the requirement to have a temporary table on disk is alleviated.